# Resource manager generating incorrect style path

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

This is a sticky one for me, I've been fiddling around for hours with no luck.

**The issue:** 
Stylesheets are being rendered out starting with /OrchardLocal/ all the time when running a site in WebMatrix. This causes stylesheets to not be found. Scripts URL's are fine. My theme is based on The Theme Machine theme which comes with orchard. When I'm adding style/script references into Layout.cshtml I am using the following code (as an example):

```
Style.Include("style.css");
Script.Include("script.js")
```

**Replicating the issue:**
Use ClickToBuild.cmd to compile a the site in release mode, then open the site in WebMatrix using the path: \build\Stage

The styles/scripts will be rendered out as (notice the OrchardLocal):

```
<link href="/OrchardLocal/Themes/MyTheme/Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Themes/MyTheme/scripts/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have tried changing the Base URL in in Orchard Admin --> Settings but this makes no difference.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with a module called Combinator. Despite excluding everything from being combined in the Exclude setting it must cache the stylesheet paths from when running in development. I also found records containing the stylesheet paths within the module's database tables. Emptying the cache within the Combinator settings resolved the issue.